# PHP cannot connect to MS SQL Server 2008 IIS

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis

I did an express install for MS SQL Server 2008 and created a database with a test table. I am running Windows Server 2008 and have IIS, PHP and MS SQL installed. I chose to go with SQL server authentication, where you would need credentials to modify or view the database. I try to print out a simple test table on a web page, but it keeps failing and only returns a white screen..

```
<?php

$server = "WS1\SQLEXPRESS";
$username = "sa";
$password = "password";
$db = "testdb1";

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password)
or die ("Cannot connect to SQL Server on $server");

$selected = mssql_select_db($db, $dbhandle)
or die ("Could not open database $db")

echo "You are connected to the " . $db . "database on the " . $server . ".";

$query = "SELECT * FROM table1";

$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);

echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>";
echo "<li>" . $row[""] . $row[""] . "</li>";

while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
  print_r($row);
}

mssql_close($dbhandle);

?>
```

Comment: Check your error log, see if you are getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the horrific white screen. Sometimes very hard to troubleshoot. Often times it's a simple missing semicolon ...

like the one here:

```
$selected = mssql_select_db($db, $dbhandle)
or die ("Could not open database $db")
```

Put a semicolon on the end of that statement and you are back in business.

Comment: Thanks for catching that small mistake.